# Javascript line-height Property with ██████

Tags: javascript, css, qr-code, line-height

I'm trying to, with a matrix (to represent black and white) display a QR code on a webpage (`<p></p>`). I'm using the ████ characters to display such, but even when the CSS property of the line-height is 0px, I still cannot remove all gaps (and the QR code doesn't read). My code and resulting image:

```
var dateTime = new Date("Nov 11, 2019, 11:40:30").getTime();
var width = 195;
var height = 20;

var qrCode = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];


var myRequest = new Request('https://rohan-bhowmik.github.io/ctf-test/qr.txt');

var wCnt = 0;
var hCnt = 0;

var tick = setInterval(function () {
    var currTime = new Date().getTime();
    var diff = dateTime - currTime;

    var dayCount = Math.floor(diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var hourCount = Math.floor(diff % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) / (60 * 60 * 1000));
    var minuteCount = Math.floor(diff % (60 * 60 * 1000) / (60 * 1000));
    var secondCount = Math.floor(diff % (60 * 1000) / (1000));
    var msCount = Math.floor(diff % (1000));

    var sentence = dayCount + " " + hourCount + " " + minuteCount + " " + secondCount + " " + msCount;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = sentence;
    var count = -1;

    if (diff <= 1) {
        document.getElementById("alive").style = "display: inline; word-wrap: break-word; line-height: 0px;";
        document.getElementById("alive").innerHTML = "";
        clearInterval(tick);
        var offSet = 0;
        var text = setInterval(function () {
            var chars = ['y', 'o', 'u', 'c', 'h', 'e', 'a', 't', 'e', 'd'];
            count++;
            wCnt++;
            if (wCnt + offSet >= width) {
                console.log(hCnt);
                document.getElementById("alive").innerHTML += "<br>";
                wCnt = 0;
                offSet = 0;
                hCnt++;
                count = 0;
            }
            var m = 59;
            var n = 0;
            if (wCnt >= m && wCnt < m+34 && hCnt >= n && hCnt < n+34) {
                if (qrCode[hCnt - n][wCnt - m] == 1) {
                    document.getElementById("alive").innerHTML += "&#9608";
                    offSet += 1.25;
                } else{
                    document.getElementById("alive").innerHTML += "&#20&#20&#20";
                    offSet += 1.25;
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById("alive").innerHTML += chars[(count) % 10];
            }
        }, 0.1);
    }
}, 1);
```

[image: The QR Code]

Comment: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/jquery-qrcode

Comment: well I tried to run your code but I get 100s of "youcheated" in the output and I am too lazy to figure out why. Was going to help, but more complicated than it needs to be. Looks like line height, but too hard to test it and see.

Comment: Given that the code you've shared seems to work and what you're actually asking about is HTML/CSS, it would be much more useful if you could include the rendered HTML instead.

Comment: try it with a span with a background color and an &nbsp; content instead of the unicode symbol, which might not be full-height on some systems. or use a table.

Comment: Guessing from screensot, decreasing `line-height` to something around `1` in CSS could make those gaps disappear.

Comment: to me the code works, no white stripes in between lines, if it is about in between characteres, did you reset letter spacing ?

Comment: @epascarello You gotta wait a bit before the QR shows up

Comment: @dandavis Interesting suggestion, I might try it

Comment: @myf Yeah, I even tried lowering it to 0px (as it is right now), so not work

Comment: Hm, strange; `line-height:0`, if really in effect, should effectively produce lines running over each other; have you tried to inspect those lines? What font-size, line-height and font-family do you see in the computed style? (as a proof it should work see my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal gaps are most likely just likely space between lines. Setting `line-height` to equal value as `font-size` (or just unitless `1`). Simple examples:

- just monospace blocks, no gaps but more rectangular and possibly light bleeding between blocks:

```html
<div style="
 white-space: pre;
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
">
███████  
█     █
█ ███ █
█ ███ █
█ ███ █
█     █
███████
</div>
```

- more square and less bleeding could be made with doubled characters stuck together with negative `letter-spacing`:

```html
<div style="
 white-space: pre;
 font-family: monospace;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 letter-spacing: -2px;
">
██████████████
██          ██
██  ██████  ██
██  ██████  ██
██  ██████  ██
██          ██
██████████████
</div>
```

Comment: Very cool, playing with the font size actually worked to remove the gaps.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using imageData. You may need to resize the pixel to get the wanted size. The rendered code is readable by qr-droid.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"> <!-- resize width and height to fit qr-code -->
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var qrCode = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var pixelSize = 5;
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(pixelSize, pixelSize);

// creates pixelSize*pixelsize "pixel of pixels"
for (let i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4){
  imgData.data[0+i] = 0;
  imgData.data[1+i] = 0;
  imgData.data[2+i] = 0;
  imgData.data[3+i] = 255;
}
  
  

  
var max_x = qrCode[0].length;
var max_y = qrCode.length;

// draw pixels according to qrCode matrix.
for (let y = 0; y < max_y; y++){
 for (let x = 0; x < max_x; x++){
  if (qrCode[y][x] == 1) ctx.putImageData(imgData, x*pixelSize, y*pixelSize);
        
 }
}

</script>

   <!-- The canvas tag is not supported in Internet 
Explorer 8 and earlier versions.-->

</body>
</html>
```

Introduction to using canvas imagedata: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_imagedata_data.asp